# Split String using multiple Selectors

Tags: regex

I have below string :

```
var deptInfo = "Flight-1 08:30~Flight-1 10:45|Flight-2 15:15~Flight-2 17:30"
```

I want to have info in the format:

```
var timeSlot = ["08:30-10:45","15:15-17:30"]
```

I am trying to split the `deptInfo` like this:

```
var timeSlot = deptInfo.split("(Flight-1 )|(~Flight-1 )").join('-').split('|').join(',').split("(Flight-2 )|(~Flight-2 )").join('-');

var timeSlot = deptInfo.split(/Flight-1 ~Flight-1 /).join('-').split('|').join(',').split(/Flight-2 ~Flight-2 /).join('-');
```

But this is not delivering the expected results. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following pattern to extract the necessary bits and then post-process the matches to get the necessary output:

```
/(\d{2}:\d{2})~Flight-\d+\s*(\d{2}:\d{2})/g
```

See  the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RWakbr/1/). Note you may even wrap the pattern with `\b` (word boundaries) if you want to make sure the first and last 2 digits are not preceded/followed with a word char, `/\b(\d{2}:\d{2})~Flight-\d+\s*(\d{2}:\d{2})\b/g`.

**Details**

- `(\d{2}:\d{2})` - Group 1: 2 digits, `:`, 2 digits
- `~Flight-\d+` - a `~Flight-` substring and then 1+ digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d{2}:\d{2})` - Group 2: 2 digits, `:`, 2 digits

JS usage:

```js
var rx = /(\d{2}:\d{2})~Flight-\d+\s*(\d{2}:\d{2})/g;
var s = "Flight-1 08:30~Flight-1 10:45|Flight-2 15:15~Flight-2 17:30";
var m, res = [];
while (m = rx.exec(s)) {
    res.push(m[1] + "-" + m[2]);
} 
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Hi @Wiktor Stribizew, your solution worked. However , I would like to return true if the timeslots comes between 00:00 to 08:00. In the res the value returned is              ["08:30-10:45", "15:15-17:30"], the result of the javascript should return false. I have written this code to make this work :    for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    var bar = /^00:^01:^02:^03:^04:^05:^06:^07:^08/;
    if (bar.test(res[i])) {
        return true
    }
};

Comment: @AmbikaTewari That is a completely wrong pattern. Try http://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/b075yv24/5/